# Tuple comprehension time profiling

Tags: python, python-2.7, profiling, tuples

lately I've been doing some time profiling of my scripts.
Wondering about tuple comprehension I've found several threads on SO pointing out two ways of doing :

- list comprehension + tuple()

  ```
  >>> tuple([i for i in xrange(1000000)])
  ```
- tuple comprehension

  ```
  >>> tuple(i for i in xrange(1000000))
  ```

I'm puzzled by the fact that `cProlile` and `timeit` tell me that the first method is faster that the second on and that the command line `time` and `kernprof` line profiler say the contrary.

Here is what I get:

```
>>> import cProfile
>>> cProfile.run('tuple([i for i in xrange(1000000)])')
1000003 function calls in 0.139 seconds
>>> cProfile.run('tuple(i for i in xrange(1000000))')
1000003 function calls in 0.478 seconds 

>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('tuple([i for i in xrange(1000000)])')
0.08100390434265137
>>> timeit.timeit('tuple(i for i in xrange(1000000))')
0.08400511741638184
```

With test_tuple_list.py:

```
tuple([i for i in xrange(1000000)])
```

And test_tuple_generator.py:

```
tuple(i for i in xrange(1000000))
```

I get:

```
$time python test_tuple_list.py
real 0m0.398s
user 0m0.171s
sys 0m0.202s

$time python test_tuple_generator.py
real 0m0.333s
user 0m0.109s
sys 0m0.234s
```

With test_tuple_list_kernprof.py

```
@profile
def test():
    tuple([i for i in xrange(1000000)])
test()
```

And test_tuple_generator_kernprof.py:

```
@profile
def test():
   tuple(i for i in xrange(1000000))
test()
```

I get:

```
$kernprof.py -lv test_tuple_list_kernprof.py
Total time: 0.861045 s

$kernprof.py -lv test_tuple_generator_kernprof.py
Total time: 0.444025 s
```

I assume that the difference I get between these profiler comes with the way they profile, but how comes they contradict one another ?

Thank you

Comment: There is *no* tuple comprehension. You have a `tuple()` type call with a generator expression.

Comment: The `timeit` results are too close to call, really.

Comment: Profiling adds too much instrumentation to be useful as a timing comparison. *Do not use it* for those purposes.

Comment: Is there a way to know which method is the fastest ? Because `cProfile`seem to show a real difference

Comment: Only use `timeit`, and the results are *too close* to call. They are about as fast as each other.

Comment: Do you know why cProfile yields such different results ?

Comment: Probably because profiling hooks are being triggered at different times for the different code paths followed. Profiling does not measure the *overall* speed, it instruments the interpreter (using [`sys.set_trace()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace).

Comment: Ok I'm not familiar enough with profiling to understand this statement :)

Comment: The Python interpreter will call into the profiler function for a whole series of events. So during the execution of the generator expression, a series of profiling events will be triggered, each slowing down execution somewhat. When running the list comprehension instead, a *different* set of profiling events is triggered, also slowing down the execution. Because the *pattern* of events differs, the total slowdown differs. You are not measuring the code anymore, you are comparing how the profiler reacts to each piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use a profiler to measure overall timing differences between two snippets of Python code. A profile *severely* impacts code execution times across the interpreter, as different code paths will trigger the [`sys.set_trace()` trace function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) at different times, and the trace function itself could introduce subtle timing differences for different events that completely skew the results making your data useless for absolute timing comparisons.

When profiling, you are as much measuring how the the profiler reacts to different code paths as that you are measuring the code paths themselves. That's fine for when you want to pinpoint *where* in complex code all your execution time goes, but it is terrible for comparing two different pieces of code purely on how fast they perform.

That leaves *just* your `timeit` results, which are too close to call. Both methods are about as fast as one another.